# React - Not able to update list of product component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I made a list of product which contains name, price etc.. properties. Then I created a simple search box and I am searching my products based on product name . the search result returns the correct object but the UI is not getting updated with that result.Initially, I am able to see the list but after searching it is not getting updated.  I am new to react SO need some help. here is my code

```js
 OnInputChange(term)
  {
    let result=   this.products.filter(product=>{
           return product.name==term;

     });
     console.log(result);


     let list=result.map((product)=>
     {
        return <li  key={product.price}>{product.name}</li>

     });
     console.log(list);
     this.setState({listOfProducts:list});
  }

    render()
    {

        this.state.listOfProducts=this.products.map((product)=>
        {
           return <li key={product.price}>{product.name}</li>

        });
       return <div>
           
           <input onChange={event=>{this.OnInputChange(event.target.value)}}/>
           <ul>{this.state.listOfProducts}</ul>
           
           </div>

    }
```

```
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.products.filter` should probably be `this.state.products.filter`

When referring to a Components method you say `this.onInputChange` but when referencing state you must say `this.state.products` because `this.products` doesn't exist.

I would also move this:

```
 let list=result.map((product)=>
 {
    return <li  key={product.price}>{product.name}</li>

 });
```

to your render statement. so your onchange handler could be:

```
OnInputChange(term)
  {
    let result=   this.products.filter(product=>{
           return product.name==term;

     });  
     this.setState({listOfProducts:result});
  }
```

and then you

```
render(){
    return(
    {this.state.listOfProducts.map(product => {
        return  <li  key={product.price}>{product.name}</li>
    })} 
    )
}
```

hope that helps! If your problem persists please share your entire code so I can better understand the issue.

Comment: i am getting this.state.products as empty

Comment: well does it exist? put the code for your entire component in your original question